# How can I get all locations in a list that are not equal to a value(without using a for loop)?

Tags: java

okay not sure if there is a better way than I'm already doing.  Right now I have a list(int[]) that has a over 10,000 values that equal 0 in it and I'm looking for only the non-zero items.

My current approach is just to do a for loop and capture all the non-zeros but I do this a lot, and profiling shows its taking a large amount of my cpu time(since I'm doing this so often).  Is there a way I can get the same results without the expensive cpu process(since out 10,000 items, only less than 100 will be non-zeros)?

Here's an example of my data:

```
int[] list = {0,0,0,1,0,10 }
int[] list_names = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

All I need to ultimately do is use these two lists to create another two lists with only the non-zero values and their names(so D=1 and F=10). I've seen some solutions where I need to sort the results before it works but thats a problem because if I sort the data list then I cannot identify its name.

Is this possible and is there a faster way compared to a for loop?

Sorry I should mention that this large lists remain in my program for processing and I'm trying to do this to reduce the memory footprint of them.  I have a queue of a few hundred million of these lists being stored in their entirety when all I really need is the non-zero values, so doing this to save memory(which seems to be working) but I'm also trying not to take a bit hit on the cpu to get it to that point(since I need the cpu for my processing).

Comment: Are the values of the list between a range, like 0 <= myList[i] <= 1000? Do you really care the value of each item on the list or just the list values that are non-zero?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The values are between 0 and 1000, and I'm only interested in the non-zero items.

Comment: Do you care about the index of each number, or just the values?

Comment: You say that less than 100 will be non-zeroes.  Do you always know exactly how many will be non-zeroes?

Comment: @SamDufel my goal is to take all the non-zeros and make a more compact list out of it, so anything I need to do that I need.

Comment: @emory no I do not know, I was just assuming that it wouldn't exceed 100, but its possible it can.  I was just trying to prove what a waste my for loop has been.

Comment: If you have to request the array from the API every single time, your most efficient solution will be a for loop.  If you're able to store it for future use, you should just sort it in descending order.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't delete the zero values?

Comment: @SamDufel I can and want to delete the zeros but they are relative to their names so I need to know the non-zero locations so I can get their names as well.

Comment: @learningJava - my suggestion then is to create 2 blank arrays when you get a list from the api - loop through the array you receive, and push all nonzero values and their labels into your blank arrays.  Afterwards, delete the original array.  (by array, I mean any data structure that you can use as a stack, doesn't have to be an actual array)

Comment: @SamDufel I'm currently doing something very similar, using a for loop and then any non-zero is going to a new list and its corresponding name list is copied to a new list.  I have to do this several million times so I was looking for a way that I could do it slightly faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know anything else about the array, then you're going to have to look at every value.  That means that looping over the whole array is basically the best you can hope for.  If it's sorted, or if you know some other information about it, that might help -- but otherwise, there are no alternatives.

Comment: I think absent some fancy quantum computer algorithm - like Grover's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) - this is the answer.

Comment: I guess what I was asking is there a better algorithm(maybe built into java or not) to do this in a more efficient way?  I'm stuck between a rock and hard place with this because on one hand if the keep these lists in memory they are huge and take space so I'm trying to process them down to a reasonable size which is hitting me on cpu utilization.

Comment: Information-theoretically, you can _prove_ that there's no way to do this without looking at every element.  I advise you to find something else to optimize in your program, because there's almost certainly no way to optimize this part.

Comment: I think your right, just thought I'd give it a shot here.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @emory, you get my upvote for the most ridiculously unfeasible (yet technically accurate) comment.

Comment: wait wait..lets explore the quantum algorithm, sounds insanely possible.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you pre-sort the list, so you can find the non-zeroes easier? the idea would be to presort once or when inserting new data. So that retrieving is already sorted and easy.

EDIT:

Then use a hash code for the table. If the hash code has not changed then you don't need to search through the list/table.

Comment: no this is not possible as I'm already getting it in this format from a api that I have no control over. It is basically just sending me an entire table of data when only the non-zero numbers are relevant(not sure why, maybe to see how much they can annoy me? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you read more often then you write, you could cache the result of your search. Create a list of non-zero items, and keep it there until the next write.

You could also keep a set of all indexes into the original array where the value is not zero. Every time you change a value in the list to zero, remove the index of that value from the set; every time you set a value to non-zero, add its index to the set. This way instead of searching for non-zero entries you would simply harvest then from the set of known indexes.

Comment: The problem is I'm constantly getting new versions of this list and really I'm just trying to make the list smaller so it takes less space than storing 10,000 item list(when all I need is like 100 items in each list). Reading maybe a problem down the road but right now I'm trying to avoid out of memory errors while I'm waiting to process results

Comment: If you are not the one maintaining these lists, you have no choice but to look through them one by one. You could optimize the part that deals with the values that you found (e.g. using an value/name hash map) but you will end up going through all items no matter what.

Comment: I suspected that, but thought I would give it a shot to see if there was some kind of optimized super algorithm that the Java Gods provided for my specific problem :-)  (guess I'm out of luck)

Answer (score 1):

It is literally impossible to do this without looking at all the elements if all you get is an unsorted array of integers.

Also note that sorting itself is worse than O(n), so sorting won't help you.

If you are somehow manipulating these arrays afterwards, it would make sense to generate a sparse representation (like a map of indexes-to-values) that you can work with.

---

Without knowing more it's hard to say what you can do, maybe there is some opportunity to speed things up by doing some work in multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the position at which you found a non-zero value. Store the index and value each in a separate array.

So `0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 7` becomes

```
int[] list_index = {1,3,5}
int[] list_value = {2,1,7}
```

Then iterate over the values in `list_index` as indices into the `names` array and store the corresponding `list_value`.

Comment: This is based on the comment: "my goal is to take all the non-zeros and make a more compact list out of it..."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a big `List<Integer>` with zero and non-zero values, keep a `List<Integer>` or even an array of counters, in this list you will only have how many times a number has been placed into it.

```
public class MyList {

    private final int MAX_SIZE = 1001;
    private int[] myList;
    private int size;

    public MyList() {
        this.size= MAX_SIZE;
        this.myList = new int[size];
    }

    public MyList(int maxSize) {
        this.size = maxSize;
        this.myList = new int[size];
    }

    public boolean add(int e) {
        if (e < 0 || (e > size - 1))
            return false;
        this.myList[e]++;
        return true;
    }

    public void remove(int e) {
        if (e < 0 || (e > size - 1))
            return;
        if (this.myList[e] > 0)
            this.myList[e]--;
    }

    public int getTimes(int number) {
        if (number < 0 || (number > size - 1))
            return 0;
        return this.myList[number];
    }
}
```